# Table for Longest prefix matching

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, kernel, ipv6

I want to build a kernel module which will maintain his own table for carrying out longest prefix match. For this purpose, I am trying to use linux's "include/net/ip6_fib.h". Is it possible to meet the required functionality through this? Am I on right path?

If answer is YES then can anyone tell me some good resource which explains the IP6 FIB API?
Thnaks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have very little kernel space experience, but from the user land perspective I know that Linux routing tables can be independent of the routing of packets. If I understood your question correctly, that is what you were asking.

AFAIK Linux routing only uses tables that are defined in the "routing policy" i.e., they have routing rules referencing them. The Linux default is to use tables "local" "main" and "default" (table numbers 255, 254 and 253). So if you put your routes in e.g. table number 100, they will not be used by the regular routing mechanisms, unless you add a rule referencing the table. You can see the routing "policy" by typing `ip rule list`. This can also be learned from the "official" iproute [documentation](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.6) which has not been updated since Alexey N. Kuznetsov wrote it at the turn of the millennium.

However, I dont know how this affects prefix matching and the ip6_fib api, since route lookups are cached (outside the routing tables). You can see the routing cache by typing `ip route list table cache`. (side note: an indepth look at the routing cache can be found at  http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ipv4-route-cache-linux.html)

I can not provide any help on using the FIB inside the kernel, which was your 2nd inquiry. I can only venture that the kernel source is the most up to date documentation and most probably also the only documentation.